# How to mock instantiated object with Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a file (src/dclient) that does this:

```
import DataClient from 'src/clients/data'

const DClient = new DataClient({ id: 'xxx' })
export default DClient
```

And I have a file (which I am trying to test) that does this:

```
import DClient from src/dclient

// Some code

DClient.alert('hello')
```

I am trying to write expectations on `Dclient.alert` but failing to do so. I have tried to set up the jest test as:

```
alertMock = jest.fn();
require('src/dclient').alert = alertMock
```

But this is not working when I check `alertMock.mock.calls` even though I know it has been called. I think because dclient returns an instance and actually doesn't have alert defined on it.

How can I set up this jest so I can write expectations on alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to test this.

The way you are trying works fine, you just need to change it to this:

```js
test('code', () => {
  const alertMock = jest.fn();
  require('src/dclient').default.alert = alertMock;  // <= mock alert on 'default'

  require('./code');  //  <= require the code that calls DClient.alert('hello')
  expect(alertMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');  // Success!
})
```

...because `src/dclient` is an ES6 module with a `default` export.

---

The approach I would probably use is to mock the `alert` function on the `DataClient` class:

```js
import DataClient from 'src/clients/data';

test('code', () => {
  const alertSpy = jest.spyOn(DataClient.prototype, 'alert');
  alertSpy.mockImplementation(() => {});

  require('./code');  //  <= require the code that calls DClient.alert('hello')
  expect(alertSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');  // Success!
})
```

Comment: I was using require('src/dclient').alert = alertMock and I should have been doing require('src/dclient').default.alert. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Jest has a really well-made [auto-mocking feature](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), which generates `jest.fn()` for each method on the exported object, so you can just:

```
import DClient from 'src/dclient'; // import the module
jest.mock('src/dclient'); // generate auto-mock

describe('alert', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        DClient.alert.mockReturnValue(true);
        // ^ not really needed in the alert case, but you'll get
        // error if the exported object doesn't have alert method
    });

    it('should have been called', () => {
        DClient.alert('hello');
        expect(DClient.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith()
    });
});
```

Comment: When doing this, I get this error `jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy`

Comment: Notice that DClient returns an instance of another file...Wouldn't that change how you mock it?